# SQL SqlDataReader: how can i confirm null

Tags: c#, sql

I have SqlDataReader which gives me 2 values,
reader.GetString(0) and reader.GetString(1), i need to create "if statement" based on different combinations of null they may contain,
for example:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   if (!(reader.IsDBNull(0)) && reader.IsDBNull(1))
   ...
}
```

when first value is not null and the second is null.
I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: What about your code doesn't work? It should execute the if branch when reader[0] is not null and reader[1] is null

Comment: So you have four conditions and have to test for all 4 possible combinations.

Comment: @JacobHuckins the error i get is something like "invalid read try, when no data available"

Comment: @jdweng exactly

Comment: If you are getting no data available then your db call isn't returning enough values.

Comment: @JacobHuckins i used ``if (reader.HasRows)``` so it wouldn't reach if statement if it didn't return any values.

Comment: Have you called reader.Read() anywhere? "The default position of the SqlDataReader is before the first record. Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data." [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Comment: @JacobHuckins works now, thanks